# Delete elements from Json file with value matches and update the Json file with leftover elements in groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to load and loop elements from the JSON file output and delete the elements if it matches the values and at last, create a new JSON. I am able to successfully delete if I have only one element in my JSON. but when I have two elements then it's failing with the "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" error.

**Existing sarva.json File content:**

```
{
    "stack-0": {
        "name": "foo-web",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z",
        "dbName": "foo-DB"
    },
    "stack-1": {
        "name": "bar-web",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z",
        "dbName": "bar-DB"
    }
}
```

I have tried with the below code to remove one element from JSON and create a new JSON. for that, I've used below code block. but unfortunately, I am getting an error.

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parse(new File("sarva.json"))
json.each { key, val ->
if ("$val.name" == "foo-web") {
  json.remove(key)
  println json
}
}

// below block is to update the new sarva.json file with the new content.

newJson = new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString()
new File("sarva.json").write(newJson)
```

**Intended output:**

```
[stack-1:[createdAt:2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z, dbName:bar-DB, name:bar-web]]

// And the sarva.json file should be updated with only "stack-1" details.
```

**Below is the error o/p i am getting:**

```
[stack-1:[createdAt:2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z, dbName:bar-DB, name:bar-web]]
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1208)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1244)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2201)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:5)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:574)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:612)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:583)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:149)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:115)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4729)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4700)
```

Any help sorting this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here: either create a new instance of your JSON as Map, or *properly* modify the existing object:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''\
{
    "stack-0": {
        "name": "foo-web",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z",
        "dbName": "foo-DB"
    },
    "stack-1": {
        "name": "bar-web",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z",
        "dbName": "bar-DB"
    }
}'''


// create a filtered new Map
def newJson = json.findAll{ key, val -> 'foo-web' != val.name }
assert newJson.toString() == '[stack-1:[name:bar-web, createdAt:2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z, dbName:bar-DB]]'

// modify the existing json
def entry
for( Iterator iter = json.iterator(); iter.hasNext() && ( entry = iter.next() ); ){ 
    if( 'foo-web' == entry.value.name ) iter.remove()
}
assert json.toString() == '{stack-1={name=bar-web, createdAt=2022-11-30T10:56:32.551977633Z, dbName=bar-DB}}'
```